# check whether all rows in a table have unique values for a column

Tags: mysql, sql

How to ***check whether all rows in a table have unique values for a column***
having char datatype in a table in MySQL and return the value as `yes` or `no` ?

Comment: `SELECT case when count(distinct column_name)>1 then 'No' else 'Yes' end FROM table_name`.

Comment: Oops, no, this is not what the OP is looking. What he is looking for is probably similar to Gordon's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, where `?` is the column you want to check :

```
SELECT IF(t.total = t.total_distinct, 'YES', 'NO') AS result
FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
            , COUNT(DISTINCT ?) AS total_distinct
       FROM tbl
) t
```

Answer (score 1):

If you ignore `NULL` values, you can just compare `count()` and `count(distinct)`:

```
select (case when count(col) = count(distinct col) then 'All Unique' else 'Duplicates' end)
from table t;
```

If `NULL` values are a concern (so `NULL` would be allowed at most one time), then you can aggregate and look at the maximum count:

```
select (case when max(cnt) = 1 then 'All Unique' else 'Duplicates' end)
from (select col, count(*) as cnt
      from table t
      group by col
     ) col
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the first version of Gordon's answer, but grouped by the Primary key of the table. In other words :

```
select  primary_key_field, (case when count(col) = count(distinct col) then 'All Unique' else 'Duplicates' end)
from table t
group by primary_key_field.
```